# I have a timer count back how do i add a new empty line like a space after the timer line?

Tags: javascript

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://risq.github.io/jquery-advanced-news-ticker/assets/js/jquery.newsTicker.js"></script>
<script>
    var count = 300;
    var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second

    function timer() {
    count = count - 1;
    if (count == -1) {
            clearInterval(counter);
            return;
    }

    var seconds = count % 60;
    var minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    minutes %= 60;
    hours %= 60;
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = hours + " Hours " + minutes + " Minutes and " + seconds + " Seconds left untill the next news update."; // watch for spelling
    }
    function news(){
   $('body').find('.newsticker').remove();//It will clear old data if its present 
   var file = "http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/test.txt";
    $.get(file, function (txt) {
            //var lines = txt.responseText.split("\n");
            var lines = txt.split("\n");
            $ul = $('<ul class="newsticker" />');
            for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i++) {
                //save(lines[i]); // not sure what this does
                $ul.append('<li>' + lines[i] + '</li>'); //here 
            }
            //$ul.appendTo('body').newsTicker({
            $ul.appendTo('div.wcustomhtml').newsTicker({
                row_height: 48,
                max_rows: 2,
                speed: 6000,
                direction: 'up',
                duration: 1000,
                autostart: 1,
                pauseOnHover: 1
            });
    });
    }
    $(function() {
    news();
    setInterval(function(){
      news();
    },30000)  // it will call every 1 min you can change it
    });
</script>
<br><span id="timer"></span><br>
```

This is my code.
This is the line of the counter:

```
document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = hours + " Hours " + minutes + " Minutes and " + seconds + " Seconds left untill the next news update.;
```

I want that it will look like:

4 Hours 5 Minutes and 10 Seconds left untill the next update

And here the text i have already..So i want there will be empty line after the counter line.

Today its like this:

4 Hours 5 Minutes and 10 Seconds left untill the next update
And here the text i have already..But without a space empty line.

I added at the bottom 
 and  around the Timer id line but it didn't help.

Comment: is "timer" a span? if so, you can add `<br>` outside of the span and it will set a new line.

Comment: Ok <br> is working if i put it inside a text for example: document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = hours + " Hours " + minutes + " Minutes and " + seconds + " Seconds left untill the next news<br> update."; so the word update will be in a new line. But i want to create/add a new empty space line under this line so all this hours minutes second time left untill next news update will be seprated from the other text. Not to break it to new lines.

Comment: It's also working outside the text as well. http://jsfiddle.net/27B8Z/

Comment: Gil watch my site please tell me whats wrong: http://newsxpressmedia.com/test.html why it's not working ?

Comment: Gil i updated my question with my code now changed as you did in the link of jsfiddle. See my site the timer line is not sperated from the scrolling text.

Comment: Actually it's working perfectly well. `<br>` sets a new line after the span. If you want it to be a double line just add another '<br>'.

Comment: Gil thanks its working i had to add two <br> now its working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `\n`, which will add a new line only in the source code, use the html br tag (`<br>`) for a new line.

Comment: better yet, wrap each line in `<p>`

Comment: Updated my question with the full code. And the change i did at the bottom i added <br> and </br> around the id timer but it didn't help.

Comment: @user1741587 `br` is a stand-alone tag, remove the `/` from `</br>` and then this tag will also work.

Comment: Not working i tried to wrap around the id timer with <br> and <br> above and under the line. Didn't work. Then i tried to wrap with <br> and <br> around the line of the hours minutes second...didn't work then i tried on each places only with one <br> above it and under it didn't make any space/new line. Still the counter is stick to the text i read from the text file.